# How do I select a value from the a different column but same row in a for loop?

Tags: python

From a CSV of various years, I am trying to total up values in another column from one particular year. For example, take arbitrary values

| years | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5 |
| 2001 | 4 |
| 2000 | 3 |
| 2002 | 6 |

and so on

with a defined value total as `total_value = 0`.

I have:

```
for year in years:
   if year == 2000:
       total_value += ???
```

where the returned value should be 8. I've tried using the .loc modifier to no avail. It's a simple question but I just can't get it right now!

Comment: _"I've tried using the .loc modifier"_: show us what you tried! Filtering a dataframe by a column is a pretty common questio.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path_here.csv')
df.groupby('years').value.sum()[2000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternative non-pandas answers, using the built in csv module.
Note that as I'm not converting the year values to ints, the target_year is in string format for comparison.

1. Using `csv.DictReader` to read each row, check the year and add the values.

```
import csv

total_value = 0
target_year = "2000"

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row["years"] == target_year:
            total_value += int(row["value"])

print(total_value)
```

2. Using `csv.reader` and `sum()` with a list comprehension to get the matching values.

```
import csv

target_year = "2000"

with open("data.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # Skip the header row
    total_value = sum([int(row[1]) for row in reader if row[0] == target_year])

print(total_value)
```

If you want to check multiple years combined, you could put them all in a list and then use something like `if row["years"] in target_years:`

Answer (score 0):

here is a way using the loc method

I assumed that the dataframe has three columns: years, value, total_value
this code sums the value of the year selected and changes it in the toal_value column in all the rows of the selected year

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("path.csv")

def total_value(year):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row["years"] == year:
            df.loc[df['years'] == year, ["total_value"]]+= row["value"]
```

I hope you found this helpful